# How do I find the html element that has been bound to a property?

Tags: validation, aurelia

How do I find the bound html element from a model's property in the controller(js file)?

I am using the new aurelia-validation errors collection and I know the name of the model's property that is in error but not the element to which it is bound and I want to set focus to it.

```
    checkForErrors() {

    // remove any other errors in case they are showing
    toastr.remove();

    let errors = this.validationController.validate();

    for (var i = errors.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        console.log(errors[i]);
    }

    // only show it if we have errors
    if (errors.length > 0) {
        let errorString = "<p> <ul class='list-unstyled'>";

        for (var i = 0; i < errors.length; i++) {

            console.log("property name : " + errors[i].propertyName);

            errorString += "<li><p onclick=\"document.getElementById('" + errors[i].propertyName + "').focus()\">" + errors[i].message + "</p></li>";
        }

        errorString += "</ul>";

        //show these errors
        toastr.warning(errorString, "Validation Errors");

        return false; // we have errors

    } else {

        return true; // no errors
    }

}
```

As you can see I am creating `<li>` items to show in the toastr. I want then to click on the `<li>` to set focus to the element that has failed it's validation. The only reference I have to it is the `errors[i].propertyName`. As a hack I have given the element a `ref=""` that is the same as the propertyName.

I'm sure there is a way of looking up (via the bindings) from the property to the element, bu I can't find what it is.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the question! If possible, please provide some code and I'll try to get you an answer.

Comment: code example added.